# SPO - Update multiple items in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, list-workflow

I want to update multiple items in a list with a value from another list using SP Designer 2013 workflow. How to achieve this? I tried it using HTTP web service option in 2013 workflow but couldn't understand it and get it working.

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow, we can user Call HTTP web service action to loop all items in the list which need to update items.

Use the steps below and add custom information in your environment which could achieve your request:

[image]

Build a dictionary as below:

[image]

[image]

The link in the Call HTTP web service action is:

[image]

In the Loop stage, you can change the “if any value equals value”condition and “Update list item” actionbased on your information.

Here are some similar posts for your reference:

[Workflow Loop Through Multiple SharePoint Items](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/)
and

[2013 Workflow Update Items in dictionary](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187608/2013-workflow-update-items-in-dictionary)

Comment: This article worked like charm. https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/  except that replace the URL with https://SiteURL/_api/web/Lists/GetbyTitle('List Title')/items?$filter=Title eq Value

Comment: if the post helps you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: If I add the call http web service within a loop, call http service processes only the 1st item in the loop. Is this expected behaviour?